# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (React, heroku)

Tags: reactjs, heroku, mongoose

```
react_devtools_backend.js:2574 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at ra (react-dom.production.min.js:156)
    at ba (react-dom.production.min.js:167)
    at Object.wa [as useEffect] (react-dom.production.min.js:167)
    at Object.t.useEffect (react.production.min.js:22)
    at hn (makeStyles.js:191)
    at p (makeStyles.js:228)
    at withStyles.js:55
    at oa (react-dom.production.min.js:157)
    at La (react-dom.production.min.js:176)
    at Vs (react-dom.production.min.js:271)
```

How do I resolve this error? I hosted my react app on Heroku using react build pack and when I try to load some pages which make API calls it shows that error, but when I run it on my local machine it runs well.

Below is the snippet of my code which I don't think causes the error

```
{ 
  !this.props.loading ? this.props.packs && 
  this.props.packs?.length > 0 && this.props.packs?.map((pack) => 
  { return <Pack key={pack.id} 
  pack={pack} onPurchasePackage={this.onPurchasePackage}/> }) : null
}
```

Comment: hi first share the code so we can help you.
second try debug in the dev tool and see where is the problem

Comment: @TalOrlanczyk thanks for responding. I don't think the error is from my code, from the snippet I shared you will see it is from "react_devtools_backend.js"

Comment: the api calls are from the same endpoint in your local machine?
i mean like the server side is the same endpoint?

Comment: @TalOrlanczyk I am not sure if I understand your question properly. But the frontend and backend are separate endpoints

Comment: I mean that the frontend call the same backend endpoint
for example:
dev: localhost:3000
staging: localhost:3000

Comment: @TalOrlanczyk Yes, it does, but I have found and fixed the problem. Thank you for your time I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue with my code. The issue was with the way I placed my material ui hoc.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withStyles(useStyles)(withErrorHandler(Packages, axios)));
```

which was wrong to

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
(withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(withErrorHandler(Packages, axios)));
```